# How to generate class with field of type Date from xs:string element with JAXB

Tags: datetime, jaxb, xml-parsing, jaxb2, xjc

I have xsd schema file which I can't change.
Here is an excerpt that makes my problem:

```
<xs:element name="Event" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="EventDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
...
```

Here is an example of string data I get for EventDate:

```
2012-05-30T12:30:00 CEST
```

I'm compiling with xjc and I get Event class with String field.
Is there a way to get Event class with some kind of Date field?
I guess I should write some kind of adapter and that's ok but I don't know how to tell xjc to use it only on EventDate element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm compiling with:

```
xjc -b temp.xml schema.xsd
```

This is part of temp.xml:

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='EventDate']">
        <jaxb:property>
            <jaxb:baseType>
                <javaType name="java.util.Date"
                    parseMethod="com.mydomain.adapters.DateAdapter.parseDate"
                    printMethod="com.mydomain.adapters.DateAdapter.printDate"
                />
            </jaxb:baseType>
        </jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

And here is part of com.mydomain.adapters.DateAdapter class:

```
private static final DateFormatter df = new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z");
public static Date parseDate(String v) {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(v, Locale.getDefault());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new MyException("Could not parse date:" + v);
    }
    return date;
}

public static String printDate(Date v) {
    return df.print(v, Locale.getDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'XmlAdapter' . It supports this functionality.

Comment: Ok but how to tell xjc to use it only on xs:string in Event klass?

Comment: Plz edit your answer so I can undo my downvote. For some reason I can't undo vote if answer is not edited.